# ios universal redirection link is not working on real device, but working on emulator

Tags: ios, react-native, redirect, react-native-ios, ios-universal-links

I am using univeral link in react native. It working on ios emulator but not working on real device.
Follow is apple-app-site-association file.

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "L439KYBPK7.com.****.****",
                "paths": [ "/auth/redirect"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Follow is xcode configuration:

[image: applink screenshot]
[image: url scheme screenshot]

As I said, app is working on ios emulator(13.4.1) but not working on real device(13.4.1), that is, after oauth complete, no redirect to app on real device.
I hope your help. Thanks for your advance.

Comment: It can take some time before the device successfully registers the site association. Deleting your app from these device can help. You can generate a [sysdiagnose](https://ios13.dev/universal-links-debugging-on-ios-13-cjwsux93w001p6ws1swtstmzc) on your device and examine the log

Answer (score 0):

Just check supporting your domain for AAPA file here:

https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/

It can take time for indexing AAPA file on device.
Remove and install application again.

And you can easy run Deeplink on emulator.
Just execute in your terminal:
xcrun simctl openurl booted YOUR_URL